# JS: How to add class to body tag and other class in one line on click

Tags: javascript

```
document.querySelector(".second")
    .addEventListener('click', () => {document.body.classList.toggle("dark");})
```

I want to add the dark class to body tag and .section and .header, etc

please help

Comment: Use `querySelectorAll` instead of `querySelector`. querySelector will return an Element object representing the first element in the document that matches the specified set of CSS selectors, or null is returned if there are no matches.

Answer (score 1):

You can do whatever you want in click listener.

```
document.querySelector(".second").addEventListener('click', () => {
  document.body.classList.toggle("dark");
  document.querySelector(".section").toggle("dark"); // Maybe querySelectorAll?
  document.querySelector(".header").toggle("dark");
});
```

But what is wrong with class only on body? If this is only for css selectors, just use:

```
body.dark .header { ... }
```

Answer (score 1):

What you need is `classList+="TheClassYouAreAdding AnotherClassYouAreAdding"`

```
 document.querySelector(".second").addEventListener('click', () => {document.body.classList+=("dark section header");})
```

You may also use `document.body.classList.add("someClass")` for individual classes

I made a pen for you: https://codepen.io/AtanasBobev/pen/QWvMYaW

Also, read this: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_element_classlist.asp
if you have any further questions, I am going to edit the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `querySelectorAll()` like this

using ES6:

```
  document.querySelectorAll('.second').forEach(el => el.addEventListener('click', () => {document.body.classList.toggle("dark");}));
```

using For Loop:

```
  const second = document.querySelectorAll('.second');
    for (var i = 0; i < cover.length; i++) {
      second[i].addEventListener('click', () => {document.body.classList.toggle("dark");});
  }
```

Now both sides of the image will trigger the event.